# My parakeet is flirting with the feeding box; does he needs a female parakeet?

Tags: behavior, breeding, birds

When I bought my third parakeet, he was shy. But after some weeks, he became so happy and funny. However, now I see he's flirting with the feeding box.

I don't know if he needs a female parakeet or he's just playing around the cage due to him only having 11 months.

If he's just playing around the cage, what can I do? Can I buy some toys for the bird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is normal, especially if your feeder has colors similar to a parakeet. It is nothing to cause concern, unless he becomes obsessed with the feeder to the point of ignoring other distractions. That's unlikely to happen if he has other toys and distractions (and plenty of attention from you, too, for companionship).

It's always good to have a variety of toys and to rotate them often (to maintain interest). They don't have to be fancy and expensive, but be careful to avoid anything toxic or anything that is sharp or presents a choking hazard. A piece of twine with a few knots in it (hung from the top of the cage), a piece of cardboard on a string, a tennis ball to push around, etc., all are inexpensive and fun toys. Just keep changing them whenever your parakeet starts to get bored with them. (You can re-use the same toys, as long as they've been stored long enough for him to have forgotten about them.)